# Vectorized implementation of an image convolve function

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I know that `numpy` includes a convolve function.

The thing is I need to write my own, I can simple write it in this form(something like that):

```
for i in range(-1, 2):
    for j in range(-1, 2):
         pixel[position1] += pixel[position2]*kernel[position3]
```

But I need to write a vectorized implementation, any help?

Thanks.

Note: I'm already using numpy and scipy, but I need to write my own function for the sake of practicing.

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/firfilter.c#L104

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own convolution can give a much faster computation, especially when you have a small kernel with lots of 1's and 0's.  For example, a convolution with

```
kernel = array([[0, 1, 0],
                [1,-4, 1],
                [0, 1, 0]])
```

could be written as

```
laplace = -4*u[1:-1,1:-1] + u[2:,1:-1] + u[:-2,1:-1] + u[1:-1,2:] + u[1:-1,:-2]
```

The advantage here is that there's only one multiplication and four additions, whereas doing the full usual convolution would amount to nine multiplications and additions.  Also, although scipy has a 2d convolve, numpy alone does not.

This is just the basic approach and there are ways to speed this up (eg, using temporary arrays, or in-place calculations), and also you have to decide what to do on the boundaries; though often the above is exactly the right thing.